# linux bpftool not found in linux-tools-common for kernel 4.19.232

Tags: linux, kernel, ebpf

I am trying to check if `bpf` is properly installed in my linux kernel. It's enabled in the kernel as shown:

```
jakew@desktop:~$ cat config | grep BPF
CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT_ALWAYS_ON=y
# CONFIG_BPF_UNPRIV_DEFAULT_OFF is not set
CONFIG_IPV6_SEG6_BPF=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPFILTER=y
CONFIG_BPFILTER_UMH=m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_BPF=y
CONFIG_NET_ACT_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_STREAM_PARSER=y
CONFIG_LWTUNNEL_BPF=y
CONFIG_HAVE_EBPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS=y
# CONFIG_TEST_BPF is not set
```

I tried to install `bpftool` to check up on `bpf`, and it seems like i need to install it via linux_tools_common with: `sudo apt install linux_tools_common`. When I tried to run `bpftool`, it showed this error:

```
WARNING: bpftool not found for kernel 4.19.232

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-4.19.232-4.19.232
    linux-cloud-tools-4.19.232-4.19.232

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-4.19.232
    linux-cloud-tools-4.19.232
```

however, `sudo apt install linux-tools-4.19.232` showed an error saying package not found.

Not sure how I can get `bpftool` to work so that I can explore more into `bpf`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to [install from sources](https://github.com/libbpf/bpftool#dependencies). That way you'll also be sure to have the latest version.

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/libbpf/bpftool.git
cd bpftool/src
make -j$(nproc)
sudo ./bpftool prog
```